# Передача символов в Netty (Java)

Tags: java, netty

Приветствую.
На сервер передается пакет, с ним буффер строки.
Вот таким методом:

```
this.mc.player.connection.sendPacket(new CPacketCustomPayload("MC|ItemName", 
      (new PacketBuffer(Unpooled.buffer()).writeString(s))));
```

Где `s` - необходимая строка.
Но при передаче на сервер, по какой то причине, он её воспринимает не так, как хотелось бы.

**Примеры**:

(1) Клиент: [image: ex1]
(1) Сервер: [image: ex1]

В первом примере все нормально, но вот на остальных..

(2) Клиент: [image: ex2]
(2) Сервер: [image: ex2]

(3) Клиент: [image: ex3]
(3) Сервер: [image: ex3]

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: покажите код сервера, где он обрабатывает строку.